# Потоки в qt вместе Postgres

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку1, можно было записывать данные, и пока это делается, нажать на другую кнопку2, и начать чтение записей из базы? (2 действия сразу делались и при этом не подвисал ui). У меня пока все стоит на локалке, при этом есть только одно соединение с базой и один юзер.

Answer (score 1):

> записывать данные, и пока это делается ... начать чтение

> только одно соединение с базой

Протокол общения с `PostgreSQL` позволяет выполнять запрос [асинхронно](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-async.html), не дожидаясь его выполнения, но в рамках одного соединения вы не можете иметь более одного выполняющегося одновременно запроса.

Потому в указанных требованиях - никак.

Вам нужно как минимум второе соединение с базой. А уже имея два соединения - вы можете это реализовать, заменив синхронный `PQexec` на `PQsendQuery` и `PQgetResult` либо что-то другое что для того же самого асинхронного взаимодействия предусмотрено в той библиотеке подключения, которую вы используете.